# JPA Repository.findByKeyEquals() returns not present value, but the value is exist on db

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, relationship, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm developing an application that queries a database.

There are a few issues right now.

> history.isPresent() == false when calling Optional<History> findByKeyEquals() intermittently. but value is exist on database

This is the information I got while tracking the issue.

> 1. All child entities are non-null.
> 2. In most cases, if the same function is re-executed, it is searched.
> 3. But sometimes it doesn't happen intermittently.

i think that i use incorrectly table relationship annotation (@OneToMany,@ManyToOne options..)

I want to solve this issue.

this is my code

History (Parent)

```
@Table(
    indexes = {
      @Index(columnList = "key", unique = true),
    })
@Entity
@Getter
@ToString
@Audited
public class History implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
  private Long id;

  @Setter
  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
  private String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

  @Setter
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @NotAudited
  private Date started = new Date();

  @Setter
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @NotAudited
  private Date finished;

  @Setter
  @OneToMany(
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      mappedBy = "history",
      orphanRemoval = true)
  @NotAudited
  private List<Content> contents = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}
```

Content (Child)

```
@Table
@Entity
@Getter
@Audited
public class Content implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
  private Long id;

  @Setter
  @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
  @NotAudited
  private String content;
  
  @Setter
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = History.class, fetch = FetchType.Lazy, optional = false)
  @Audited
  private History history;
  ...
}
```

Repository

```
public interface HistoryRepository
    extends JpaRepository<History, Long>, RevisionRepository<History, Long, Integer> {

  Optional<History> findByKeyEquals(final String key);

}
```

Comment: Hi, did you try renaming `findByKeyEquals` to `findByKey` ?

Comment: thank you for comment.
It was a bug related to the database transaction scope...